# Mechanics of Select for update in Soql

Tags: soql, transaction

I am curious how `select for update` is internally implemented in Salesforce?

Is the locking done in the application layer or is it propagated to the DB layer?

I know that Salesforce supports multiple underlying databases, I wonder how it works across all database types.

What type of locks are used, shared or mutex?

The more information, the better.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I don't believe this level of detail on the underlying implementation is public.